# Can Qt run in Android?

Tags: android, qt

I'm working on Qt and I want to know if Qt can run in android too because i want to buy a tablet
that it's operating system is android.

Answer (score 11):

There is a port of Qt for Android called [Necessitas](http://necessitas.kde.org/).

More info:

- [Quickstart video](http://labs.qt.nokia.com/2011/02/28/necessitas/)
- [Android-Qt Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/android-qt)

Answer (score 0):

i found this [qt on android](https://www.kdab.com/qt-on-android-episode-1/) very interesting when i started android dev with qt